# WPF ProgressBar - make the progress bar completed after the operation finished

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, backgroundworker, system.diagnostics

I have a WPF form which runs a background operation with progress bar. but the problem is that;

when the operation is completed, the progress bar is still running. I mean it shows like the operation is in progress.

how can I stop that? here is my whole code;

```
System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker mWorker;

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

    mWorker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
    mWorker.DoWork +=new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
    mWorker.ProgressChanged +=new System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
    mWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    mWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    mWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
    mWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

    while (pbProcessing.Value != 100) {

        if (!mWorker.CancellationPending) {

            try {

                pbProcessing.Value = (pbProcessing.Value + 0.01) % 100;

            } catch (System.Exception ex) {

                // No action required
            }

        } else {

            MessageBox.Show(this, "Process cancelled", "Cancel Process", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            break;

        }

        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
               new System.Threading.ThreadStart(delegate { }));

    }

}

private void worker_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e) {

    // Do your work here, its on seperate thread
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

}
private void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {

    pbProcessing.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

}
private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {

    // Stop Progressbar updatation  
    Window1 w = new Window1();
    w.Browser.Navigate(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com"));
    w.Show();

}

private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) {

    if (mWorker != null) {

        if (mWorker.IsBusy) {
            mWorker.CancelAsync();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean it is still running?  Is it not at 100%?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to hide the progressbar after the work is done, set its `Visibility` property to `Visibility.Hidden`. If you just want to reset it to its initial state, set it's `Value` to `0` (or to `pbProgressing.Minimum`, if you changed that from its default value).

---

As a side note, your code doesn't really make sense: Instead of continuously changing `pbProcessing.Value` in the button event handler (which is completely useless, since no UI updates are performed until the button event handler has completed), you should only change the value in `ProgressChanged`. I.e., your code should look something like this:

```
System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker mWorker;

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

    mWorker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
    mWorker.DoWork +=new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
    mWorker.ProgressChanged +=new System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
    mWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    mWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    mWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
    mWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

    // Don't do anything else here

}

private void worker_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        mWorker.ReportProgress(i);

        // Do some part of the work
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

        // Check if the user wants to abort
        if (mWorker.CancellationPending) {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
    }

    mWorker.ReportProgress(100);  // Done
}

private void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
    pbProcessing.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {

    // Stop Progressbar updatation  
    Window1 w = new Window1();
    w.Browser.Navigate(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com"));
    w.Show();

    // Check the result
    if (e.Cancelled) {
        // show the message box that the task has been canceled
    }

    // Reset Progress bar
    pbProcessing.Value = 0;
}

private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) {
    if (mWorker != null) {
        if (mWorker.IsBusy) {
            mWorker.CancelAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @heinzi thanks for the reply. I have been setting the value 100 after the progress completed :) thanks for the tip.

Comment: Also, I wanna ask that the progress bar is not all sync with the process. how can I make it sync with the progress.

Comment: @heinzi it should be e.Cancelled inside the worker_RunWorkerCompleted method I guess.

Comment: @heinzi yes, it is all in sync now. it is going to be off topic a little bit but at the beginning, it is showing the progress a little late. how can we start that when the process starts.

Comment: @tugberk_ugurlu_: Yes, you are right, it should be e.Cancelled. The "little late" might be because the Thread.Sleep is done before any update to the progress bar. I've replaced that with a loop and shorter sleep times, so it should be more reactive now. Just remember that you need to replace Thread.Sleep with code that actually does some useful work. ;-)